# make async.waterfall start with argument from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, steam

I have bumped into a problem that I can't seem to solve. This is for a steam trading bot and it works well except for when two people trades with it at the same time because class_id and other_id are global variables and they will change in the middle of a trade if more than one is using it.

I tried defining the variables inside the last if statement but then get_class_id did not find the variables. Is there any way the async function can take item.classid and convert_id_64(offer.accountid_other) directly without defining them as variables? I appreciate any help.

```
var class_id
var other_id

function accept_all_trades(offers_recieved) {
offers_recieved.forEach( function(offer) {
    if (offer.trade_offer_state == 1) {
        if (typeof offer.items_to_give === "accept") {
            offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(error, response) {
                console.log('accepterat offer');
                offer.items_to_receive.forEach(function(item) {
                    if (item.appid === '420') {
                        class_id = item.classid;
                        other_id = convert_id_64(offer.accountid_other);
                        console.log(class_id);
                        async.waterfall([get_class_id, get_stack, get_name, get_save], add_names);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
}

function get_class_id(callback) {
var test = class_id
callback(null, test)
}
```

Update

I've changed the code to what ben suggested but still when I call get_class_id and try to print the id it is just a blank row in the console, any Ideas?

```
function get_class_id(callback) {
console.log(class_id);
var test = class_id;
callback(null, test)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not aysnc.waterfall().  It's async calls (offers.acceptOffer(), get_class_id, get_stack, get_name, get_save, add_names) inside regular javascript forEach().  You need control-flow loops that can control the flow of those async calls.  Here is the revised code using async.each():

```
function accept_all_trades(offers_recieved) {
    async.each(offers_recieved, function(offer, eachCb) {
        if (offer.trade_offer_state !== 1 || typeof offer.items_to_give !== "accept") {
            return eachCb(null);
        }
        offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid}, function(error, response) {
            console.log('accepterat offer');
            async.each(offer.items_to_receive, function(item, eachCb) {
                var class_id;
                var other_id;

                if (item.appid !== '420') {
                    return eachCb(null);
                }
                class_id = item.classid;
                other_id = convert_id_64(offer.accountid_other);
                console.log(class_id);
                async.waterfall([
                    function(waterfallCb) {
                        var test = class_id;
                        console.log(class_id);
                        waterfallCb(null, test);
                    },
                    get_stack,
                    get_name,
                    get_save,
                    add_names
                ], eachCb);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                eachCb(null);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I updated the code to what you suggested but I can still not print class_id with get_class_id() any other suggestions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: try console.log("item: %j", offer) before if (offer.trade_offer_state !== 1, also try console.log("item: %j", item) before if (item.appid !== '420') and see what you get, it might not gets to class_id because those conditions might fail

Comment: No because if I do console.log(class_id) and console.log(other_id) right before the waterfall it prints the right numbers into the console but it prints a blank line when I print it in the get_class_id function and then throws an error because get_stack does not get the value. So it seems like async.waterfall can't take a local variable from within a function this way. Is there another way it could read the variable?

Comment: You can use javascript's closure by putting get_class_id() right into waterfall's array as an anonymous function.  Plese see edited answer for this.

Comment: It worked! So for a function within a async waterfall to be able to take varaibles it has to be defined within the waterfall? Thank you so much for your help, it means a lot to me.

Comment: Yes, to take advantage of javascript closure, it needs to be defined in any level under where class_id is defined, it cannot be outside of class_id.